# "variable is not a function" error while reading knockout variable

Tags: knockout.js, prototypejs, observable

I am using prototypejs and knockout in my web project.

First of all let me explain the overall structure.

I have a base class named as userViewModel and an observable variable named accNumber is declared in this class definition.

```
 userViewModel = Class.create(baseViewModel , {
        accNumber: ko.observable("")
});
```

There is another class which is derived from my base class and a computed variable named accNumberComputed is declared in this derived class.

```
 femaleUserViewModel  = Class.create(userViewModel , {
        accNumberComputed : ko.pureComputed({
                read: function () {
                   return this.accNumber();     
                },
                write: function (value) {
                    this.accNumber(value);
                },
                owner: this
        })
});
```

I want to update accNumberComputed variable depends on the accNumber observable variable. So that any modification on the accNumber variable will be tracked on the accNumberComputed variable.

But any `this.accNumber()` statement usage returns a
"TypeError: this.accNumber is not a function" error message.
As far as i know an observable variable must be read by using  a function call operator.

Could you please enlighten me about this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dig a little deeper, you'll find out that in your example `this.accNumber` is not only *not a function*, it's actually `undefined`.

The `this` in your computed's `read` method refers to `window`.

I'm not familiar with the prototypejs library, but there's probably a way to get it to bind to the instance correctly.

I had a quick glance at the documentation, and did see a way that resembles how it'd work in a "plain javascript approach". It works like this:

1. Don't add the observable and computed to the prototype, but create them in the constructor. (`initialize` in prototypejs)

This:

```
 var userViewModel = Class.create(baseViewModel , {
   accNumber: ko.observable("")
 });
```

becomes:

```
var userViewModel = Class.create(baseViewModel, {
  initialize: function() {
    this.accNumber = ko.observable("");
  }
});
```

2. Explicitly call the base class' constructor in the extended class' constructor.

Not sure if it's the best way of doing it, but can be done like:

```
var Extended = Class.create(Base, {
  initialize: function() {
    Extended.superclass.prototype.initialize.call(this);
```

In your example, this is what you'll get:

```js
var baseViewModel = Class.create({
  initialize: function() {
    this.base = "base";
  }
});

var userViewModel = Class.create(baseViewModel, {
  initialize: function() {
    this.accNumber = ko.observable("1");
  }
});

var femaleUserViewModel = Class.create(userViewModel, {
  initialize: function() {
    femaleUserViewModel.superclass.prototype.initialize.call(this);
    
    this.accNumberComputed = ko.pureComputed({
      read: function() {
        return this.accNumber();
      },
      write: function(value) {
        this.accNumber(value);
      },
      owner: this
    })
  }
});

var janeDoe = new femaleUserViewModel();
console.log(janeDoe.accNumberComputed());
janeDoe.accNumberComputed(2);
console.log(janeDoe.accNumberComputed());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.3/prototype.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```